# Consulta sql para modificar registros relacionados de dos tablas, MySQL Server con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la tabla docente con el campo `usuario_idusuario`, que esta relacionada con la tabla usuario al campo `idusuario` y necesito modificar la tabla docente y los campos de la tabla usuario que pertenecen al `idusuario` relacionado a la tabla de docente

```
//campos de la tabla docente

$id = $_POST['ID'];
$nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$direccion = $_POST['Direccion'];
$usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
$contraseña = $_POST['Contraseña'];




$sql = "UPDATE docente SET iddocente='$id', nombreDocente='$nombre', telefonoDocente='$telefono', emailDocente='$email', direccionDocente='$direccion', INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario_idusuario=usuario, usuario_idusuario='$usuario' contrasena='$contraseña' WHERE iddocente = '$id'";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

la tabla usuario contiene los campos

```
-idusuario <-- campo relacionado a la tabla docente usuario_idusuario
-usuario
-contrasena
```

Comment: Qué error te marca? pon la estructura de ambas tablas

Comment: La consulta SQL no esta bien :c

Comment: pon el error que te marca, y pon las estructuras de las tablas, de otra forma es difícil saber